# Why siAssignableFor return false for Class Implementing Interface

Tags: java

I have following class :

```
public class DialogChooseMemberController extends ControllerFX implements FXMLDialogController<AnchorPane, List<Member>, Member> {
}
```

for  loading controllers I have helper enum where I provide class as parameter, to load screens dialogs etc....

```
public enum FxScreenLoader {
    PANE_OPEN_PROJECT(PaneOpenProject.class),
    PANE_PROJECT_MAIN(PaneProjectMain.class),
    PANE_MEMBER(PaneCreateDisplayMember.class),
    PANE_RELATION_ADD_PARENTS(PaneAddParents.class),
    PANE_CHOOSE_MEMBER(DialogChooseMemberController.class);


    @Getter
    @Setter
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Getter
    private Class<? extends FXMLPane> fxClass;

    (..)

    public Object showDialogOnStage(Stage stage, Object content) {
        System.out.println("Chooose");
        System.out.println(" FXCLASS" +fxClass);
        if (!fxClass.isAssignableFrom(FXMLDialogController.class)) return null;
        System.out.println("Not null");
        FXMLDialogController controller = (FXMLDialogController) context.getBean(fxClass);
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = controller.getRoot().getScene();
        if (Objects.isNull(scene)) scene = new Scene(controller.getRoot());

        controller.setContent(content);
        initDialogProperties(dialogStage, Modality.WINDOW_MODAL, stage, scene, false);
        controller.setStage(dialogStage);
        dialogStage.showAndWait();
        return  controller.getResult();
    }
```

Unfortunately when I load method for  DialogChooseMemberController  it return false each time.

There is any othe rpossibility to check if my class implements specific interface ?

Comment: To test if `(FXMLDialogController) context.getBean(fxClass)` will work without causing ClassCastException, you need to test the other way around `FXMLDialogController.class.isAssignableFrom(fxClass)`, since that is the assignment you're doing, i.e. assigning *to* `FXMLDialogController` *from* `fxClass`

Comment: aah ok so I inversed order